# Flask-restful app fails when authentication is enabled

Tags: python, flask-restful, flask-httpauth

I'm getting this error whenever I try and enable authentication using flask_httpauth for my flask_restful project:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

Here's a very basic example:
apicontroller.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flasktest import api, app
from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth

auth = HTTPTokenAuth()

@auth.login_required
class ApiController(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return True

api.add_resource(ApiController, '/api/apicontroller')
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, session, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse, fields
from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth


app = Flask(__name__)

api = Api(app)

import flasktest.apicontroller
```

Whenever I decorate the controller class with `@auth.login_required`, it fails with the mentioned error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you cannot not apply decorators to class.

To solve that:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flasktest import api, app

from flask_httpauth import HTTPTokenAuth

auth = HTTPTokenAuth()

class ApiController(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

    def get(self):
        return True

api.add_resource(ApiController, '/api/apicontroller')
```

Comment: awesome! You rock!

Comment: @Trondh also you could probably wrap only `get()` function with your decorator, but i'm not sure about it. Cheers!